# Sources to learn the exchange server with sharepoint

Tags: exchange

Are there any good online sources to learn exchange with sharepoint quickly. I mean to get the finest overview. BTW I don't know anything about exchange server.

Comment: @sam sorry not to mention with Sharepoint. I am not sure how big is the exchange server subject.

Answer (score 1):

There are a hug amount of resources available on Exchange, it depends what you want to learn. However some of the best resources include:

- [You had me at EHLO](http://msexchangeteam.com/) ( the MS Exchange team blog)
- [MSExchange.org](http://www.msexchange.org/)
- [Technet Exchange Tech Center](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I tried that route and ended up having to dig myself out of a sizeable mess resulting from a lack of understanding about how Exchange stores data.  Internet self-teaching has the benefit of being free.  It lacks completeness.  I'd highly recommend picking up a book or two if you just want the essentials relatively quickly.

Comment: I think you are right. Same happened to me with DNS things. I was absolutely confused by all the information on the net.

Comment: all the same info is out there, but lately the time it takes to identify and organize it is in too short of a supply...